# PL/SQL: dynamic query in clob string. How can i open a cursor?

Tags: plsql, cursor, oracle10g

I am using Oracle 10g and I have problems with Open for Query_string.

that query string is a dynamic query, it has more than 7000 charcaters.

how can I open a cursor with varchar2 (which in 10g only accepts max length of 4000)? At the moment I tried using CLOB instead of but **open..for** doesnt accept it.

In the header is declared: `TYPE tref IS REF CURSOR;`

```
DECLARE
    SQL CLOB;    
BEGIN
   SQL := '...';

   OPEN tref FOR SQL
END
```

the version 10g not accepted is:

```
DECLARE
    SQL VARCHAR2(8000);    
BEGIN
   SQL := '...';

   OPEN tref FOR SQL
END
```

Thx

Comment: Even in Oracle 10, a PL/SQL variable can hold up to 32767 bytes: [Quote from the manual](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/datatypes.htm#sthref732) "*The VARCHAR2 datatype takes a required parameter that specifies a maximum size up to 32767 bytes*"

Comment: anyway calling from .net to the store procedure says me the error of max length. obviouslly using 12g is no problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok guys

I got the solution, when you have **CLOB**, you can use **dbms_lob.substr**...

```
OPEN p_ref FOR dbms_lob.substr( SQL, 32000, 1 );
```

Comment: it is working very well this option for Oracle 10g and Oracle 12g